# CSS menu, not displaying correctly with one option

Tags: css, menu

I'm trying to use this CSS menu
https://codepen.io/StephenScaff/pen/bVbEbJ

But when I remove some entries from the menu, the flyout appears all the time.

This example shows all but one entry removed from the 'Shop' menu, this results in 'Derps' always being shown. https://codepen.io/pen/wvyxVKQ

This is what I've changed the 'Shop' menu to be:

```
<li>
     <a href="#"><i class="ion-bag"></i> <span>Shop</span></a>
          <ul class="nav-flyout">
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="ion-ios-color-filter-outline"></i>Derps</a>
            </li>
            
          </ul>
        </li>
```

Can anyone advise what needs to be changed in the CSS to have this display correctly, so even with one entry the flyout remains hidden until the menu entry is hovered over ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve this by adding a fixed width to the flyout.  Now it displays correctly.